# Connection proplem "Couldn't establish a secure connection"

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I get this message while surfing established websites.  I press "OK" and website comes back and I can continue but message keeps reapearing. Very annoying.  Any clue to fix ?

Comment: Without more details: probably not. Can you name some example sites? A good guess is they either have no valid certificate, or using a self-signed one.

Comment: Major sites i.e. Philadelphia Inquirer,  ESPN, CNN etc. ?.... happens with most sites.